# 3g device not detected as modem in debian lenny

Tags: debian-lenny, modem, 3g

In debian lenny, the modem of my 3g usb device is not detected. It is detected as a storage device. I am using wvdial to connect internet. The logs, dmesg and var/log/messages shows the device is detected as a storage device.

Answer (score 0):

you shoud install minicom and disable storage / cd function in yours 3g modem via AT commands. 
then you shoud have several /dev/ttyUSBXXX for audio / commands / log

Answer (score 0):

If upgrading to current-stable Squeeze is an option, then you could use the [usb-modeswitch](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/usb-modeswitch) package.